# An issue with generics types in method parameters

Tags: scala, generics

can someone explain why the code below doesn't work?

```
scala> abstract class A[T] {}
defined class A

scala> class B {}
defined class B

scala> object C extends A[B] {}
defined object C

scala> def method(arg: A[Any]): Unit = {}
method: (arg: A[Any])Unit

scala> method(C)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : C.type
 required: A[Any]
Note: B <: Any (and C.type <: A[B]), but class A is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
       method(C)
```

I have an abstract class, here named `A`, and I'd like to be able to pass anything that extends A[AnythingHere] as an argument to the method `method`. In Java I would write `public void method(A<?> arg) {}`, but I don't know how to make it work with Scala, as there is no `?`.

I also tried adding that `+` to the `+T`, but after testing and searching for what it does, I didn't find it helpful here. Just the warning disappeared

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://www.julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2013/02/21/be-friend-with-covariance-and-contravariance/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code does not work because if you want to use generics in *variant* or *contravariant* in Scala, you have to declare it explicitly. Otherwise, the Java *invariant* behaviour is implemented.

Java is by default *invariant*. This means that if `A` `<` `B`, then`List[A]` and `List[B]` do not have any hierachical relationship between them.

Scala lets you to use declare generic type as covariant or contravariant, which means

1. If you declare a generic as covariant, then if if `A` `<` `B`, then`List[A]` `<` `List[B]`. To do this, you have to declare the generic using the syntax `class A[+T]`
2. If you declare a generic as contravariant, then if if `A` `<` `B`, then`List[A]` `>` `List[B]`. To do this, you have to declare the generic using the syntax `class A[-T]`

Comment: can you please add a short example of the correct code?

Comment: I am doing...wait a minute :)

Comment: As far as I can see, the `+` can't be put after `T`, or tell me if I'm doing something wrong ;) or should I replace that `+` with something? `scala> class D[T+] {}
<console>:1: error: ']' expected but identifier found.
class D[T+] {}`

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your explanation; I think I understood it, but I'm still not quite sure how to make use of it in my particular situation. How should I declare `A` and the method to be able to pass *anything that extends the abstract class `A`* (or, can be, trait `A`) as an argument? is `Any` the good word here? Look at my code please, and try to tell me :) I'll be very grateful!

Comment: Have you tried to simply secolare the parameter of the method as A[_] and generic type of A as covariant?

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the `_` thing

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use: `def method[T](arg: A[T])`

This means that you don't need to change the variance of the class definition.